# Bug of using floating number in Titanium sdk

Tags: javascript, floating-point, titanium

I found a very wired problem for floating number in titanium. Since I have to input floating number for some modules, I must use floating number solution, please don't answer me with string method.

Below is the problem: When I try Ti.API.info(94.1), it shows me 94.0999999....
I thought that is javascript problem, BUT when I tried it on browser(jsbin.com), it perform normal.i.e. alert(94.1), it showed 94.1

Thus, I made a little try below:

```
for (var i = 0; i<1000; i++)
  Ti.API.info(i+0.1);
for (var i = 0; i<1000; i++)
  Ti.API.info(i+0.2);
for (var i = 0; i<1000; i++)
  Ti.API.info(i+0.3);
for (var i = 0; i<1000; i++)
  Ti.API.info(i+0.4);
....
```

Below are the unusual outputs in Titanium(but usual in browser, e.g. 64.1)

```
[INFO] : 64.09999999999999
[INFO] : 65.09999999999999
[INFO] : 66.09999999999999
[INFO] : 67.09999999999999
[INFO] : 68.09999999999999
[INFO] : 69.09999999999999
...
[INFO] : 70.09999999999999
[INFO] : 71.09999999999999
[INFO] : 72.09999999999999
[INFO] : 73.09999999999999
[INFO] : 74.09999999999999
[INFO] : 75.09999999999999
[INFO] : 76.09999999999999
[INFO] : 77.09999999999999
[INFO] : 78.09999999999999
[INFO] : 79.09999999999999
[INFO] : 80.09999999999999
[INFO] : 81.09999999999999
[INFO] : 82.09999999999999
[INFO] : 83.09999999999999
[INFO] : 84.09999999999999
[INFO] : 85.09999999999999
[INFO] : 86.09999999999999
[INFO] : 87.09999999999999
[INFO] : 88.09999999999999
[INFO] : 89.09999999999999
[INFO] : 90.09999999999999
[INFO] : 91.09999999999999
[INFO] : 92.09999999999999
[INFO] : 93.09999999999999
[INFO] : 94.09999999999999
[INFO] : 95.09999999999999
[INFO] : 96.09999999999999
[INFO] : 97.09999999999999
[INFO] : 98.09999999999999
[INFO] : 99.09999999999999
...
[INFO] : 8.199999999999999
[INFO] : 9.199999999999999
...
[INFO] : 8.300000000000001
[INFO] : 9.300000000000001
...
[INFO] : 64.40000000000001
[INFO] : 65.40000000000001
[INFO] : 66.40000000000001
[INFO] : 67.40000000000001
[INFO] : 68.40000000000001
[INFO] : 69.40000000000001
[INFO] : 70.40000000000001
[INFO] : 71.40000000000001
[INFO] : 72.40000000000001
[INFO] : 73.40000000000001
[INFO] : 74.40000000000001
[INFO] : 75.40000000000001
[INFO] : 76.40000000000001
[INFO] : 77.40000000000001
[INFO] : 78.40000000000001
[INFO] : 79.40000000000001
[INFO] : 80.40000000000001
[INFO] : 81.40000000000001
[INFO] : 82.40000000000001
[INFO] : 83.40000000000001
[INFO] : 84.40000000000001
[INFO] : 85.40000000000001
[INFO] : 86.40000000000001
[INFO] : 87.40000000000001
[INFO] : 88.40000000000001
[INFO] : 89.40000000000001
[INFO] : 90.40000000000001
[INFO] : 91.40000000000001
[INFO] : 92.40000000000001
[INFO] : 93.40000000000001
[INFO] : 94.40000000000001
[INFO] : 95.40000000000001
[INFO] : 96.40000000000001
[INFO] : 97.40000000000001
[INFO] : 98.40000000000001
[INFO] : 99.40000000000001
...
```

I have also tried something like, parseFloat(x.toFixed(1)), Math.round(x*10)/10.....etc, it outputed the same.
Help

Comment: mult it by 100 for a precision of 2 do your calculation then divide by 100, `(.1*100+.35*100)/100=.45`, while `.1+.35=.449999999999`

Comment: i tried both
but still not solved in Titanium.

Comment: Then use something like `parseFloat((.1+.35).toPrecision(12)) = .45` while `.1+.35=.44999999`. `Ti.API.info(parseFloat((i+.35).toPrecision(12)));`

Comment: When I try on web browser
parseFloat((49.1).toPrecision(2)) = 49.1, 

But when I tried it in Titanium, 
parseFloat((49.1).toPrecision(2)) = 49.09999......

Comment: You coult trick it like this `Ti.API.info(''+parseFloat((i+.35).toPrecision(12)));` it will display a string

Comment: But the problem is, I have to use the value later for a module, and the module only accept floating number.

Comment: Cannot use parseFloat in your module?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31388/discussion-between-jonathan-de-m-and-calvin-chan)

Comment: What is the problem you want to solve? Do you expect to exactly represent numbers like 94.1 in binary floating-point? That is impossible. You can display numbers with one decimal point so that the floating-point approximation to 94.1 appears as “94.1”. You can design calculations so that the approximations do not drift so far from decimal values that the decimal values cannot be recovered. You can scale numbers so that exact arithmetic can be performed. For specific advice, you must describe your problem more clearly.

Comment: Let me explain in detail, 
I am making an app with titanium paypal module, one of the properties: subtotal can only accept a floating number, so I have to change the value to floating number for using the module. 

Below is the expected result in browser: 
jsbin.com/alokut/1/edit 

Below is the weird situation in Titanium: 
https://jira.appcelerator.org/secure/attachment/39576/%E8%9E%A2%E5%B9%95%E5%BF%AB%E7%85%A7%202013-06-07%20%E4%B8%8B%E5%8D%8806.19.37.png

Comment: @CalvinChan: This is expected behavior for `parseFloat`. It is **impossible** for a binary floating-point number to be exactly 94.1. If `subtotal` only accepts a float and is expected to work for 94.1 dollars, then it **must** accept the value near 94.1 in place of exactly 94.1. That is poor design for software designed to handle currency, so you might want to check whether it is supposed to be passed in units of cents instead of dollars. Do you have documentation for it?

Comment: I have checked the document, nothing about the floating point problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution myself.

I modified the module project in TiPaypalPaypalButton.m,

rounding the `[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:[[args valueForKey:@"subtotal"] stringValue]]` to 2 decimal places by  `decimalNumberByRoundingAccordingToBehavior`.

Thanks all.